# ¿Cómo liberar un puerto usado en java?

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con sockets, el problema es que utilicé el puerto 7979 para que lo reconociera y se conectaran el server y el cliente, pero al realizar otra práctica java me dice que el puerto está utilizado. ¿hay algún método o forma de liberar los puertos para reutilizarlos?

Lo que encuentro en la red es "problemas con el puerto 8080" y más temas relacionados al 8080.

Comment: Cierra la aplicación que está usando dicho puerto. Otra cosa que puedes hacer es que si identificas que el puerto está en uso, puedes usar otro puerto para conectarte.

Comment: Creo que el problema es porque has cerrado la aplicación y no has cerrado el socket de la aplicación, reiniciando el pc sigue dándote el problema? ¿Qué SO tienes?

Comment: Podrías incluir el código que has usado ?
así vemos como gestionas el socket y si cierras la conexión debidamente
De todas formas reiniciando la el ordenador debería liberarse

Comment: Si abres y cierras puertos constantemente, te recomiendo la lectura de este excelente tutorial: [A Guide to Java Sockets](http://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets), hay ejemplos de código sobre abrir y cerrar puertos implementando una clase que gestione de forma adecuada dichas tareas.

Answer (score 2):

Ya que el error está en pedir un nuevo registro para ese puerto que ya fue pedido:

```
    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
    }
```

Con el get obtienes el ya existente.